# How to avoid that syntax : (Format(R.Date_VL,'') = Format(M.Date,'') => making macro very slow

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I just realized that (Format(R.Date_VL,'yyyy/mm') = Format(M.Date,'yyyy/mm') is why my script is very slow.

Do you know why and if there is a way to avoid that syntax ?

its very very slow when I use format = format !!

Edit : I want to join on months and years not days

```
SQL = "SELECT M_Net_Flow.ID_Perf, M_Net_Flow.Net_Flow AS XX, laps"
SQL = SQL + " INTO AAA"
SQL = SQL + " FROM M_Net_Flow INNER JOIN R_Dates ON (Format(R_Dates.Date_VL,'mm/aaaa') = Format(M_Net_Flow.Date,'mm/aaaa'))"
SQL = SQL + " GROUP BY M_Net_Flow.ID_Perf, M_Net_Flow.Net_Flow, laps"
SQL = SQL + " HAVING (LAPS < " + deb + ");"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: Extracting the year and the month might be quicker? `FROM M_Net_Flow INNER JOIN R_Dates ON ( (YEAR(R_Dates.Date_VL) = YEAR(M_Net_Flow.Date)) AND (MONTH(R_Dates.Date_VL) = MONTH(M_Net_Flow.Date)) )`

Comment: It's way better thanks. To your information : before 2min25 and now 54secs. Thanks!

Comment: I also tend to make one variable out of year-month, `year(a.date)*100+month(a.date) = year(b.date)*100+month(b.date)`.  I don't know if it's any quicker to eliminate the compound 'Where'...

Comment: Im going to give it a shot. 'where' solution from Gustav is longer than 'YEAR'()... Thanks everyone, I think the subject has been well informed ! I close the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try using *DateDiff*:

```vb
SQL = "SELECT M_Net_Flow.ID_Perf, M_Net_Flow.Net_Flow AS XX, Laps "
SQL = SQL + "INTO AAA "
SQL = SQL + "FROM M_Net_Flow, R_Dates "
SQL = SQL + "WHERE DateDiff("m", R_Dates.Date_VL, M_Net_Flow.Date) = 0 "
SQL = SQL + "GROUP BY M_Net_Flow.ID_Perf, M_Net_Flow.Net_Flow, laps "
SQL = SQL + "HAVING Laps < " + deb + ";"
```